# SIM7020E NB-Iot module does not respond to AT commands

Tags: putty, at-command, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Using a Raspberry Pi Pico, Waveshare NB-IoT SIM7020E module and a Twilio Super SIM card I fitted the Raspberry Pi Pico into SIM7020E module using header pins:

[image]

To send AT commands to configure the modem and set up the APN I use MicroPython and copy-pasted Python code into Putty after doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to run the code. Functions to send AT commands are `uart.write`, `uart.any` and `uart.read`:

```
#Send an AT command - just return the response
def send_at_get_resp(cmd, timeout=1000):
    # Send the AT command
    uart.write((cmd + "\r\n").encode())
    # Read and return the response (until timeout)
    return read_buffer(timeout)

#Read in the buffer by sampling the UART until timeout
def read_buffer(timeout):
    buffer = bytes()
    now = ticks_ms()
    while (ticks_ms() - now) < timeout and len(buffer) < 1025:
        if uart.any():  # check if there is anything to be read
            buffer += uart.read(1)  # read 1 characters, returns a bytes object
    return buffer.decode()

#Send an AT command - return True if we got an expected otherwise False
def send_at(cmd, back="OK", timeout=1000):
    # Send the command and get the response (until timeout)
    buffer = send_at_get_resp(cmd, timeout)
    if len(buffer) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

send_at("AT")
send_at("ATE1")
```

- After sending AT command “AT” and “ATE1”, `uart.read` reads ‘b\x00’, not the AT command. SIM7020E module does not respond (I should receive the response “OK”).
- `Read_buffer` (picture 2) that reads the command in buffer by sampling the UART returns an empty string.

Before sending AT commands I powered the module on and off to boot the modem using Pin(14) of the SIM7020E module. When powered on the module’s LED switches on so Python code can communicate and the problem occurs for AT commands only. Typing AT commands "AT" and "ATE1" in Putty (I did not press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to break to the Python REPL) received an error message:

[image]

[AT command tester for Simcom modules](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/download-at-command-tester-for-simcom-modules/) recognised the port but could not connect. It suggests other baud rates and enable flow control but that did not work. Flow control I do not know how to configure.

[image]

How can I make my module respond to AT commands?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are using the right serial interface in Putty. When you send your AT commands directly in Putty what is the COM5 port? It should be the COM port that shows up under the modem in the device manager.